# Add html to page edit view within wagtail admin

Tags: admin, customization, wagtail

how can I add some text or html within the "page edit view" in wagtail admin? I want to give them some more information's about a page they are working at.

(Editors can use $variables$ in there text and I want to show them all available variables for a specific page.)

[Example how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhz5i.png)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to define a custom panel for the editing interface. Wagtail has the `FormSubmissionsPanel` panel (see [the source code](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/v1.13.1/wagtail/wagtailforms/edit_handlers.py#L10-L37)) which displays a number of form submission while editing [a form page](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/forms/index.html). You can use it as a starting point.

If you just want to render a static template with some additional information for editors your panel definition will looks similar to this:

```
class BaseInfoPanel(EditHandler):
    template = "path/to/your/template.html"

    def render(self):
        return mark_safe(render_to_string(self.template))


class InfoPanel(object):
    def __init__(self, heading=None):
        self.heading = heading

    def bind_to_model(self, model):
        return type(str('_InfoPanel'), (BaseInfoPanel,), {
            'model': model,
            'heading': self.heading or "Additional info",
        })
```

In your page model you would be able to use it as

```
class MyPage(Page):
    # fields...

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InfoPanel(),
        # or InfoPanel("My info panel") to specify heading for a panel.
        # other panels ...
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an idea how to pass MyPage object instance to BaseInfoPanel?

Comment: Found it! self.instance is referring to MyPage instace :)